# How does wait know about interrupt in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

`Thread.interrupt` interrupts such calls as `sleep`, `join` and `wait`. I wonder how it is exactly implemented.

I know `Thread.interrupt` sets a flag `isInterrupted`. Does `wait` just polls this flag ? I hope it does not. So my question is how `wait` "knows" about interrupt.

Comment: tried exploring the java source?

Comment: `wait()` is a native method :-) so no source

Comment: @sanbhat: all of openjdk is open source, including native VM implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait()` does not poll. `interrupt()` checks the state of the interrupted thread. If it runs, it just sets the flag. If it is in `wait()`, `sleep()`, or `join()`, the interrupting thread also queues it to processor. When interrupted thread resumes execution, it first checks the flag, and throws InterruptedException if the flag was on.

Comment: Thanks. Does the `interrupt` work the same way for other blocking calls: e.g. `Process.waitFor` ?

Comment: Yes - see corresponding javadoc. Interrupting I/O operation may not work (see other stackoverflow questions).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please say how exactly it is implemented ?

Comment: For "exactly", learn underlying O/S. Java relies entirely on the O/S capabilities.

Comment: Suppose I have POSIX with pthreads. How would you implement interrupting blocking i/o in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Wait and join work differently than sleep, wait / join does not check interrupted flag. If you interrupted a thread which later calls sleep() it is interrupted, but if it calls wait() or join() nothing will happen.

Comment: Javadocs say: _If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException._

Comment: Yes, but you asked if wait just polls this flag -- it doesnt.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for misunderstanding. Now I wonder how it is actually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a OS concern, as the system is handling the thread not JVM. Each OS deals with threads in different way

Comment: Sure. I wonder how it is implemented in Linux with pthreads, for example.

Comment: @Michael, it will eventually come down to an OS synchro call - event, condvar or semaphore.  Such calls take the calling thread out of the ready state and so are not available for dispatching onto a CPU.  The thread is then just 'dead' code that receives no execution. Signals from another thread, such as Notify and Interrupt, or the expiry of a Sleep, will make the thread ready again and, when a CPU core becomes available, running.